# If then else not working in Android/Confusion with final

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a problem in Android. I would like to set a `drawable` conditionally and change a `boolean` at the same time.

If a `button` is clicked, it gets a frame and a `boolean` is set to `true`. If it is clicked again, the frame vanishes and the `boolean` is set to `false`.

Only the first part of the if is working. So if I click the `button`, the frame is set, but in case I click again, it does not vanish. The two `drawables` are defined correctly.

This sets `onClickListeners` to `buttons` within an `array`.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < dice.length; j++) {
        final Button temp = dice[j];
        final boolean locked = isLocked[j];
        final int finalJ = j;
        dice[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setLock(locked, finalJ, temp);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is the called method `isLocked` is an `array` the contains the `booleans` belonging to the `buttons`. I know this not the smartest/best solution, but due to the rest of the code it was required.

```
public void setLock(boolean locked, int finalJ, Button button) {
    if (!locked) {
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dice_locked));
    } else {
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dice));
    }
    isLocked[finalJ] = !isLocked[finalJ];
}
```

Could anybody help?

Comment: I also checked, that the value of the boolean is set/changed correctly. It changes correctly, but the interface does not match the boolean.

Comment: yeah, because `locked` is the value of `isLocked[]` when you assign it. it does not follow the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final boolean locked = isLocked[j];
```

here the value is frozen and never changes in the following calls inside the `OnClickListener.onClick(View v)`.

The array item is changed though (the 1st time only - what you have observed).

To make it right, get rid of `locked` param:

```
public void setLock(int finalJ, Button button) {
  boolean locked = isLocked[finalJ];
  ....
  isLocked[finalJ] = !isLocked[finalJ];
}
```

Comment: I would like to add one more thing. Replace `temp` with `v` in method call.

Comment: you could also set button's tag with the index value

Comment: I also feel setting tag would be much better than passing the index to the method.

Comment: Thanks, that helped :) I was a little confused by the finals and forget that they can't be changed ;)